# When do expansions in ANSI-C quoting and in locale-specific translation happen?

Tags: bash

From bash manual

> Words of the form `$'string'` are treated specially. The word expands to string, with
>   backslash-escaped characters replaced as specified by the ANSI C standard
>
> A double-quoted string preceded by a dollar sign (‘$’) will cause the string to be translated
>   according to the current locale. If the current locale is C or POSIX, the dollar sign is ignored.
>   If the string is translated and replaced, the replacement is double-quoted.

I wonder when the kinds of expansions happen?

I guess they must happen after parsing. If that is correct, when do they happen with respect to shell expansions such as brace expansion, parameter expansion, and filename expansion?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`$'...'` works just like any other quoting, except it just gives alternate ways of presenting some characters.

These both print `{foo,bar}`:

```
echo $'\x7b'foo,bar}
echo "{"foo,bar}
```

...while this triggers brace expansion and prints `foo bar`:

```
echo {foo,bar}
```

Given `foo=abc`, these print `$foo`:

```
echo $'\x24'foo
echo "$"foo
```

...while this expands the variable, and prints `abc`:

```
echo $foo
```

If there's a file called `abc.txt`, these print `abc.txt`:

```
echo "a"*.txt
echo $'\x61'*.txt
```

I can only assume the same is true for `$".."`.

Comment: great examples :)